# How do I retrieve and process image files from an Android studio?

Tags: javascript, android-studio, file-io

How can I get the image file and then read the name of the image file?

I don't know how little bitmap works.

Comment: Could you be more specific about which image file you're referring to?

Answer (score 0):

1) Move your image into the `drawable` folder

2) In your activity's XML layout file (ex. ActivityMain.xml) add:
`<ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/myImage" android:id="@+id/myImage" />`

3) Where you need the bitmap:
`Bitmap bm = ((BitmapDrawable) ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cImg)).getDrawable()).getBitmap();`

Also, Java is not JavaScript, please remove your tag. Keep coding!

Comment: thank you!

i know move into the drawable folder.

I want to import pictures from SDcard, print them, and know the name of the file.